# How to use proc format with regexp option?

Tags: regex, sas, format

I stumbled upon there is a `regexp` option in **`proc format`**, so I give a try on this and get fuzzled finally.

```
proc format;
  invalue test
  '/n\(.*\)/i'(regexp) = 1
  ;
run;

data _null_;
  x = 'n(ADT,TRTDT)';
  y = input(x,test.);
  z = prxmatch('/n\(.*\)/i',x)^=0;

  put y = z = ;
run;
```

I had thought that the `regexp` option is equal to `prxmatch()` in data step, but the truth is I am wrong.

```
NOTE: Invalid argument to function INPUT at row 466 column 9.
y=. z=1
x=n(ADT,TRTDT) y=. z=1 _ERROR_=1 _N_=1
```

I have searched on help documentation and get nothing really help.
How does the option `regexp` in `proc format` works? Feel free to share your opinoin, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined an informat with a default width of 10 and tried to read a string of length 11.

```
data _null_;
  x = 'n(ADT,TRTDT)';
  y1 = input(x,??test.);
  y2 = input(x,??test20.);
  z = prxmatch('/n\(.*\)/i',x)^=0;
  put (_all_) (=);
run;
```

Results:

```
x=n(ADT,TRTDT) y1=. y2=1 z=1
```

You can add the DEFAULT= option to the INVALUE statement to change the default width.

```
proc format;
  invalue test (default=40)
    '/n\(.*\)/i'(regexp) = 1
  ;
run;
```